# unity запросы в сеть с android

Tags: android, unity3d, httpwebrequest

доброго времени суток пытаюсь обращаться к серверу на проверку bot nobot  сервер редиректит на nobot если передать полный user-agent

```
IEnumerator GetRequest(string uri)
{
    using (UnityEngine.Networking.UnityWebRequest webRequest = UnityEngine.Networking.UnityWebRequest.Get(uri))
    {
      webRequest.SetRequestHeader("user-agent", @"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; <Android Version>; <Build Tag etc.>) AppleWebKit/<WebKit Rev> (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/<Chrome Rev> Mobile Safari/<WebKit Rev>");
      webRequest.SetRequestHeader("accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8");
        // Request and wait for the desired page.
        
        yield return webRequest.SendWebRequest();
        Debug.Log("Started Coroutine at timestamp : " + Time.time);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
        Debug.Log("Finished Coroutine at timestamp : " + Time.time);
        if (webRequest!=null)

        {
            Debug.Log("webRequest!=null" + webRequest.ToString());
           
            URlreqest = webRequest.url.ToString();
   
            if (URlreqest.Equals("https://nobot/"))
            {

                Debug.Log("URlreqest.ToString()" + URlreqest.ToString());
                Invoke("NoBot", 6f);
             
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("URlreqest.ToString()" + URlreqest.ToString());
                Invoke("Bot", 6f);

            }

            //Debug.Log("webRequest.uri  "+webRequest.uri);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("null");
        }
    }
}
```

в самой юнити в лог возвращает   Debug.Log("URlreqest.ToString()" + URlreqest.ToString()); все как надо и отрабатывает nobot
но когда тестирую на реальном устройстве в логах возвращает адрес на который обращался
в чем может быть проблема ? заранее благодарен )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

все само собой решилось , просто билд надо было делать через gradle